# How do i make thos work on any windows pc

Tags: python-3.x

So i wanted to make a program it grabs images from a certain path but it doesn twork on any other device than mine i dont wanna change the paths everytime so is there anyway to make

```
teti= open('C:/Users/hyper/OneDrive/Desktop/Database/Gpus/Nvidia/Nvidia-2080ti.txt', 'r')
```

global accross all windows platforms

Comment: What do you mean? Everyone running this needs to have that exact file in that exact path... How can you enforce that?

Comment: so when i move this to my laptop or something i dont want to have to change the paths manually

Comment: Don't change the path, make sure you have that path on your computer...

Comment: i dont really understand waht you mean, sorry

Comment: You say you don't want to change the path, but want it to work on any computer. That means you need every computer to actually have that path. For instance, have a `hyper` user. I don't have that for example. Maybe you should make the path an input to the program?

Comment: so how would i make user global

Comment: make the path an input to the program and pass the relevant path on each machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make it global for every computer, unless all the computers have same path like this on:

> C:/Users/hyper/OneDrive/Desktop/Database/Gpus/Nvidia/Nvidia-2080ti.txt

What you can do, is to place the file that you want to read in the same directory as your python program. For example your input file `Nvidia-2080ti.txt` is located in folder called `Nvidia`, place your python program in the same folder and replace this `open()` with this one simply:

```py
teti = open('Nvidia-2080ti.txt', `r`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make it global you better search for the file you needed. You can just add this function and give your file name only (if you use windows) else you should give all the directories in a list in order to find the path

```
import os
# this is for windows searching all the directories with os.walk
def find_files(filename, search_path=["C:","D:","E:"]):
   result = []
   for i in search_path:
       for root, dir, files in os.walk(i):
          if filename in files:
             # this is to append the absolute path of the file
             result.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, filename)))
             break
       if len(result)!=0:
          break
   return result
# searching my own .txt  file 
print(find_files("xxx.txt"))


Output :
['C:\\Users\\TONY STARK\\Desktop\\ProgrammingAssignment2\\xxx.txt']
```